# Keepalived configuration for VRRP

Tags: keepalived, vrrp

I am trying to understand if there is a relation between garp_master_delay and advert_int. In all the configurations I saw, **advert_int** was less than **garp_master_delay**.

- Is there any reason for this?
- Are those independent of each other or is there any ordering requirement between the two?

**VRRP RFC** does not seem to mention anything on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They aren't really related, per se - the `advert_int` controls the interval between advertisements in normal operation, whereas the `garp_master_delay` controls how long after taking master state a node should sent gratuitous ARP (to notify devices that it now controls those IPs at a new MAC address to override their ARP caches).  You'd tune the two for different reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Shouldn't it make more sense for `garp_master_delay ` to be 1s or less? That way all devices will know about the master sooner. Why does it default to 5s, which looks like a larger value?

Comment: @AbhishekChanda My guess is the rather conservative default is for compatibility reasons.  In a case where you're failing back and forth rapidly (usually due to communication problems between the VRRP nodes) you don't want both nodes spewing GARP constantly - I've seen network devices start completely ignoring ARP from an offending IP address in those kinds of cases.

Comment: This exact thing happened to us. Primary failed, secondary took over, primary came back up really quickly and we had conflicting arp tables everywhere. It took a few minutes to diagnose which sucked...